# Augmenting  $t$-dimensional sub-spaces into $t+1$-dimensional sub-spaces through a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, co.combinatorics

Let $V_1, V_2, ..., V_n$ be $t$-dimensional sub-spaces of an $n$-dimensional  vector space $V$
 where $t \lt n$.

Under what conditions the following would be true:

for any $B= \{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\}$ a basis of $V$, there is a permutation $\pi \in S_n$ such that

for all $1 \leq i \leq n$,   dim$($span$(V_i \cup v_{\pi(i)})) = t +1$ ?

Comment: Isn't this just the condition you get from Hall's theorem? 

Answer (score 1):

Taking the $V_i$ as given, Hall's Theorem gives a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of **some** vectors $v_1,v_2,...v_n$ satisfying your condition.  Namely:  The complement of any $V_i$ is non-empty, the complement of any $V_i\cap V_j$ $(i\neq j)$ contains at least two elements, the complement of any $V_i\cap V_j\cap V_k$ ($i,j,k$ all distinct) contains at least three elements, etc.

I expect that if you work carefully through the proof of Hall's Theorem, you can piece together a method for determining whether any **particular** $v_1,v_2,...v_n$ satsifies your needs.

Comment: Aside to hbm --- if you are not familiar with Hall's Theorem, it is also called Hall's Marriage Theorem and is easily searchable with those keywords. 

Comment: I forgot to mention that the $V_i$ are not necessarily distinct. 

Comment: hbm:  "I forgot to mention that the $V_i$ are not necessarily distinct".  It doesn't matter.

Comment: I reedited the question to reflect what I really wanted to say in the first place.

Comment: hbm:  Following your re-edit, I reiterate my answer.  Have you tried working through the proof of Hall's Theorem?